# Garbage Collection for inside initialized Object

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have simple scenario in which one object is initialize inside other object. I want to understand that if outer object is garbage collected then Is inside object also garbage collected?

for example :

```
Class A {
   private String id;
   private B b = new B(); //Note Here

   public void doOperationOnB(){
       //operations on object B
   }

   //NO getter/setter to object B

   //setter/getter for id

}

Class B {
   private String id;   

   //setter/getter for id

}

public static void main(){

           A a = new A(); //initialization
           a.doOperationOnB();

           a = null;
}
```

If a is garbage collected then is b also garbage collected?

Comment: Don’t take my word for this, but I believe that the garbage is collected when nothing points to a piece of memory. In this case, by setting `a` to `null`, nothing points to the former value of `a` and is thus collected.

Answer (score 0):

If object A and object B are not referenced by other object (which is connected to GC root object) than both are garbaged.

Reccomend you to read this [article](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> ...if outer object is garbage collected then Is inside object also garbage collected?

An object is eligible for GC if nothing that isn't also eligible for GC has a reference to it. So in your case, if nothing else has a reference to the object held by `b`, yes, it's eligible for GC.

**However**, suppose you had this getter on `A`:

```
public B getB() {
    return this.b;
}
```

And your code were:

```
A a = new A();
a.doOperationOnB();
B newReference = a.getB(); // Getting a reference to A's `b`
a = null;
```

Now, although the object that `a` used to refer to is eligible for GC, the object that `a.b` used to refer to is **not**, because there's an outstanding reference to it in `newReference`. (Of course, if this is in `main` and `main` is about to return, that reference doesn't last long, but...)

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `a` to `null` does **not** guarantee garbage collection.

If the reference to instance `b` in `a` is not used by other objects, it is **likely** that `b` will be garbage collected when `a` is.

Answer (score -1):

The inner object will be garbage collected if the outer reference it the only reference to that object. If you had getters/setters for B, or passed this B in then it is possible there is another reference to the object.

Comment: The inner object is *eligible for* garbage collected if there are *zero* references to it. Period. If instance methods inside A are executing, there must be a reference to A in the caller, which in turn holds a reference to B, which is suffice ttomorevtnB from being garbage collection.